# findViewById returning null after being inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I've narrowed it down to three lines of Java code:

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_tile, parent, false);
    System.out.println(view.findViewById(R.id.text_view));
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

And here's the corresponding XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This prints null. Why does it print null? Why can't it find the text view?

Yes, the XML file is named "item_tile.xml", no there isn't another one named the same thing somewhere. I've tried creating new files and throwing this code in there but I still have this exact same error. Why is findViewById(...) failing?

Comment: First, I would check your imports. Make sure that you're not accidentally static importing `android.R`. Then I would say check your `build.gradle` and make sure that your source sets aren't changed. Next I would check to see if the view is just not yet inflated. Just do `Log.d(TAG,  "View: " + view);` and see what shows up. Last I would say your project is somehow corrupted. And that it a tough one to fix.

Comment: Typically you do `findViewById` inside the ViewHolder constructor, but yes, that is odd if you are sure you are inflating the correct layout.

Comment: @ChadBingham I don't think `android.R.id.text_view` is a valid resource identifier.

Comment: @cricket_007 You're right. It isn't.

Comment: Check res/layout-vXX folders for other item_tile layouts without text_view view

Comment: when you called parent.getContext() is the parent a fragment?

Comment: Check you R folder and look at the value of the "text_view" id you created. If it is < 0 findViewById will return null

Comment: In my case; I had another layout with same name in a different module.